# How can I make a beautiful table view on a website page ? Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-datatables

Need help with the design of the text on the site page,I display the data of the table and they do not look good (attached a screenshot) help
my view file:

```php
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('title')Бізнес@endsection
@section ('main_content')
    <h1>Бизнес</h1>
    <p>
    @foreach ($business as $singleBusiness)
        <li>{{ $singleBusiness->id}}</li>>
        <li>{{ $singleBusiness->name}}</li>>
        <li>{{ $singleBusiness->mail}}</li>>
        <li>{{ $singleBusiness->website}}</li>>
        @endforeach
        </p>
@endsection
```

[my plate looks like this, all records are vertical(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgouv.png)

Comment: There's a lot of issues with your post; you say "table view", but you're using `<p>` and `<li>` elements, which is not a `<table>`... You also have double `>>`, which is outputting `>`... Take a look at the documentation for HTML tables and try to use that: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp (or Google search "HTML Tables", etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, laravel has bootstrap from the box, so you can use it. This is the easiest way to get a good table

You can get tabel html from this page and then put your data in it

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/tables/

Samthing like this

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">name</th>
        <th scope="col">mail</th>
        <th scope="col">website</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($business as $singleBusiness)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ $singleBusiness->id}}</th>
            <td>{{ $singleBusiness->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleBusiness->mail}}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleBusiness->website}}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanksss soooooo much